# Oracle Java 7 on Linux PowerPC

Tags: java, oracle, powerpc

I give up trying to figure this one out on my own.

The information on this website:
http://www.yellowdog-board.com/viewtopic.php?t=2935
and on this one:
http://kapsulax.blogspot.jp/2008/08/java-plugin-under-linux-ppc.html
Is way outdated. IBM no longer creates rpm files for installing the linux powerpc version of oracle java.

I've got my reasons for wanting to switch from openjdk to oracle's Java but this is almost impossible to do on linux for PowerPC. IBM as we all know is a huge supporter of the powerpc architecture and actually has some kind of version of Java which supposedly runs on linux for powerpc but there are ZERO instructions on how to get it installed.

The files available are .bin files which after running seem to extract something into my /tmp folder which seems to have java binaries but I don't think these binaries are ubuntu compatible because they don't work O_o and the javac binary is nowhere to be found.

Anyone know where I can get a .deb or .rpm of java 6 or 7 the jre and jdk for linux powerpc?

**UPDATE MARCH 23, 2013**
I get this error on install and can't figure out where to go from here

```
./ibm-java-sdk-7.0-4.0-ppc-archive.bin 
Preparing to install...
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...

Unhandled exception
Type=Illegal instruction vmState=0x00000000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000010 Signal_Number=00000004 Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000001
Handler1=0FB25D60 Handler2=0FA53D60
R0=5FAC9DEC R1=4882EF40 R2=48839930 R3=4B845488
R4=5FAC9DEC R5=001ED8B5 R6=2F21E3DC R7=6F1D6F66
R8=5FAC9DEC R9=6F1D6F66 R10=2F21E3DC R11=0FB140D4
R12=4B845488 R13=4894BF00 R14=48980EA0 R15=00000000
R16=4BF1A1A5 R17=4BEDEF48 R18=0FBD88B0 R19=0000000C
R20=4BEA43D4 R21=48980EDC R22=489B8300 R23=00000000
R24=00000000 R25=0FBD62F0 R26=4894BF78 R27=4BEDD698
R28=000E0002 R29=0F2CD75C R30=0FBD7FE0 R31=FFFFFF00
NIP=0F2963E0 MSR=0208F932 ORIG_GPR3=00000017 CTR=0F276398
LINK=0F2765AC XER=20000008 CCR=28006222 MQ=00000000
TRAP=00000700 DAR=4BF1A000 dsisr=42000000 RESULT=00000000
Module=/tmp/install.dir.27614/Linux/resource/jre/lib/ppc/default/libjclse7b_26.so
Module_base_address=0F228000
Target=2_60_20130205_137358 (Linux 3.2.0-4-powerpc)
CPU=ppc (1 logical CPUs) (0x3ef21000 RAM)
----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
(0x0FA40F4C [libj9prt26.so+0x14f4c])
(0x0FA52840 [libj9prt26.so+0x26840])
(0x0FA40FF8 [libj9prt26.so+0x14ff8])
(0x0FA411CC [libj9prt26.so+0x151cc])
(0x0FA40BD4 [libj9prt26.so+0x14bd4])
(0x0FA52840 [libj9prt26.so+0x26840])
(0x0FA40C8C [libj9prt26.so+0x14c8c])
(0x0FB27008 [libj9vm26.so+0x1f008])
(0x0FB264CC [libj9vm26.so+0x1e4cc])
(0x0FA52840 [libj9prt26.so+0x26840])
(0x0FB25EF4 [libj9vm26.so+0x1def4])
(0x0FA53F14 [libj9prt26.so+0x27f14])
__kernel_sigtramp_rt32+0x0 (0x00100370)
(0x0FB4ECF0 [libj9vm26.so+0x46cf0])
(0x0F23FE60 [libjclse7b_26.so+0x17e60])
(0x0FB74E80 [libj9vm26.so+0x6ce80])
(0x0FB75088 [libj9vm26.so+0x6d088])
(0x0FB30558 [libj9vm26.so+0x28558])
(0x0FB1A608 [libj9vm26.so+0x12608])
(0x0FB449D8 [libj9vm26.so+0x3c9d8])
(0x0FB3BF70 [libj9vm26.so+0x33f70])
(0x0F286FDC [libjclse7b_26.so+0x5efdc])
(0x0F291980 [libjclse7b_26.so+0x69980])
J9VMDllMain+0x1c0 (0x0F291BA0 [libjclse7b_26.so+0x69ba0])
(0x0FB6041C [libj9vm26.so+0x5841c])
(0x0FB9F088 [libj9vm26.so+0x97088])
(0x0FB60198 [libj9vm26.so+0x58198])
(0x0FB5B700 [libj9vm26.so+0x53700])
(0x0FA52840 [libj9prt26.so+0x26840])
(0x0FB5A728 [libj9vm26.so+0x52728])
JNI_CreateJavaVM+0xa4 (0x0FB40E24 [libj9vm26.so+0x38e24])
JNI_CreateJavaVM+0xb14 (0x0FC18BB4 [libjvm.so+0xbbb4])
JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x2e0 (0x0FD7C6A0 [libjvm.so+0xd6a0])
(0x0FF8F4B8 [libjli.so+0x44b8])
(0x0FFCCABC [libpthread.so.0+0x7abc])
clone+0x84 (0x0FE9BA64 [libc.so.6+0xf4a64])
---------------------------------------
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "gpf", detail "" at 2013/03/25 13:14:09 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/tmp/install.dir.27614/core.20130325.131409.27614.0001.dmp' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I System dump written to /tmp/install.dir.27614/core.20130325.131409.27614.0001.dmp
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/tmp/install.dir.27614/javacore.20130325.131409.27614.0002.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /tmp/install.dir.27614/javacore.20130325.131409.27614.0002.txt
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/tmp/install.dir.27614/Snap.20130325.131409.27614.0003.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /tmp/install.dir.27614/Snap.20130325.131409.27614.0003.trc
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "gpf", detail "".
```

For some reason ... I wonder if the problem isn't related to how a couple years before, IBM provided RPMs to install these binaries on RedHat machines. So it was easy with "alien" to convert the rpm to a .deb and install it from there.

Now they are just executable .bin files and most likely configured for RHL machines. Wondering if I have to convert them somehow to work on debian based machines. No?

**UPDATE MARCH 25, 2013**
After trying the approach on this site:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1116368

I get stuck at the following error.

```
fakeroot make-jpkg ibm-java-sdk-6.0-0.0-linux-ppc.tgz 
Creating temporary directory: /tmp/make-jpkg.cGVM3tioQh
Loading plugins: /usr/share/java-package/common.sh /usr/share/java-package/j2re.sh /usr/share/java-package/j2sdk-doc.sh /usr/share/java-package/j2sdk.sh /usr/share/java-package/j2se.sh /usr/share/java-package/oracle-j2re.sh /usr/share/java-package/oracle-j2sdk-doc.sh /usr/share/java-package/oracle-j2sdk.sh

Detected Debian build architecture: powerpc
Detected Debian GNU type: powerpc-linux-gnu

No matching plugin was found.
Removing temporary directory: done
```

The directory in /tmp that it says is created, disappears and the .deb file is not created.

It amazes me that IBM does not provide install instructions on their site... who is supposed to be able to use these files !?!?

Comment: See if this helps [How-to: Installing IBM-Java on PowerPC](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1116368)

Comment: Thankyou @Mitch, a user on that page left a .deb file that installed without fuss. I just had to fix a couple symbolic links and works perfect

Comment: too bad it is for java 6 and not the newest java 7 but still better than nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's how I got it working:

@Mitch in a comment above was helpful in providing a link

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1116368

at the bottom of this page another commenter actually created a .deb file that would install ibm-java-6 and it worked perfectly for me.

http://3dslice.net/downloads/PrimeGen/ibm-j2sdk1.6_1.6.0_powerpc.deb

unfortunately at the time of writing , this link is broken and the instructions on the previous page do not work either. Also at the time of writing IBM provides the JRE for java 7 but not the sdk so if you want them both you will need to follow the directions below.

Sign up here and download the sdk bin file for java 6

find the bin file for "32-bit IBM POWER"

then make sure you change to the html installer

you will then have to create an account and sign in, in order to download the file

All you need to do is download the sdk file because the JRE is included in it

```
tgz package (InstallAnywhere)
ibm-java-sdk-6.0-13.1-linux-ppc.bin  (98 MB)
```

After you download this file I like to put all my non repository installs into the /opt folder but you may not care, however that is what I will be doing.

Make a new folder

```
sudo mkdir /opt/JavaIBM
```

copy the java sdk that you downloaded into the JavaIBM folder. This step really is not completely necessary.

to unpack the bin file all you need to do is run it as you would any script. Hope you have not uninstalled any older versions of java at this point because you will need java in order to install this.

make the file installable

```
cd /opt/JavaIBM

sudo chmod a+x <java .bin filename>
```

run the script

```
sudo ./<java .bin filename>
```

a java installer will pop up and just go through the prompts.

NEXT YOU WILL HAVE TO UPDATE YOUR SYSTEM TO USE THE NEW JAVA

I will be using the instructions on this page

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

```
Edit the system PATH file /etc/profile and add the following system variables to your system path. Use nano, gedit or any other text editor, as root, open up /etc/profile.

    Type/Copy/Paste: sudo gedit /etc/profile
    or
    Type/Copy/Paste: sudo nano /etc/profile

9
Scroll down to the end of the file using your arrow keys and add the following lines below to the end of your /etc/profile file:

    Type/Copy/Paste:

    JAVA_HOME=/opt/JavaIBM/ibm-java-ppc-6
    PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
    JRE_HOME=/opt/JavaIBM/ibm-java-ppc-6/jre
    PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
    export JAVA_HOME
    export JRE_HOME
    export PATH

10
Save the /etc/profile file and exit.
```

Notice at this point that the sdk and the jre are both in the same ibm-java-6 folder
The sdk folder is just the main folder and the jre folder is actually called jre

be careful

```
Inform your Ubuntu Linux system where your Oracle Java JDK/JRE is located. This will tell the system that the new Oracle Java version is available for use.

    Type/Copy/Paste: sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/JavaIBM/ibm-java-6/jre/bin/java" 1
        this command notifies the system that Oracle Java JRE is available for use
    Type/Copy/Paste: sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/opt/JavaIBM/ibm-java-6/bin/javac" 1
        this command notifies the system that Oracle Java JDK is available for use
    Type/Copy/Paste: sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/opt/JavaIBM/ibm-java-6/jre/bin/javaws" 1
        this command notifies the system that Oracle Java Web start is available for use

12
Inform your Ubuntu Linux system that Oracle Java JDK/JRE must be the default Java.

    Type/Copy/Paste: sudo update-alternatives --set java /opt/JavaIBM/ibm-java-6/jre/bin/java
        this command will set the java runtime environment for the system
    Type/Copy/Paste: sudo update-alternatives --set javac /opt/JavaIBM/ibm-java-6/bin/java
        this command will set the javac compiler for the system
    Type/Copy/Paste: sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /opt/JavaIBM/ibm-java-6/jre/bin/javaws
        this command will set Java Web start for the system

13
Reload your system wide PATH /etc/profile by typing the following command:

    Type/Copy/Paste: . /etc/profile
```

be careful that you know where your java files got installed and that you understand that the sdk is the root folder that was created ibm-ppc-java-6 or whatever name it was and that the jre is the jre folder inside of that folder... both folders have bin folders but they are slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

The PowerPC FAQ has this covered: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#How_do_I_get_faster_Java.3F

It links to the Java community wiki page that has instructions on IBM Java.  Yours truly wrote them, can't remember much though.  Java 7 wouldn't work for me either, but 6 will.  You will have to take up the problem with IBM, it was reported on their forum if I remember correctly, but possibly no official bug report?

Comment: Where is the appropriate place/forum to inform IBM of the problem with Java 7?